# Компиляция внутри программы

Tags: python

Допустим, имеется исходный текст программы на C++ text.cpp и компилятор MSVC10. Нужно скомпилировать и запустить средствами python'а эту радость, и считать результат компиляции. Если нет ошибок, то запустить скомпилированную программу, и считать её выходные данные. Порылся в пакете os, но ничего не нашел.

**Добавлено.**

Спасибо, вроде работает. Еще один момент: команды сохраняются в кодировке ансии, а в консольке винды windows-1251. Как исправить ситуацию? `# -*- coding ... -*-` и `result.encode` дают нулевой результат в таком коде:

```
import os

result = os.popen("ping google.com").read()

print result
```

Comment: Попробуйте в гугле

>python выполнить внешнюю программу

посмотрите [например это](http://proft.me/2009/04/9/zapusk-vneshnih-prilozhenij-v-python/) или что-то еще (ссылок там много)

Comment: `os.system` - depricated. Лучше использовать модуль [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html). А для работы с pipe'ами запущенного процесса можно использовать класс [Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, вопрос задавался для версии python 2.7. Однако в связи с неактуальностью данной версии, дам ответ для версиии python 3.+

На данный момент данная задача решается через пакет `subprocess`. Проблем с кодировкой можно избежать, если задать ее изначально. При этом обращу внимание на то, что вывод системы поступает не в кодировки консоли `cp1251`(который может быть настроен пользователем), а в системной кодировке `cp866`. Именно эту кодировку и нужно указывать.

```py
import subprocess

# создаем объект вызова программы с перенаправлением стандартных каналов вывода и ошибок
pop = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "google.com"], encoding='cp866', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# считываем данные из перенаправленных каналов вывода и ошибок
out = pop.stdout.read()
err = pop.stderr.read()

# печать результатов
print(" ОШИБКИ ".center(80, '='))
print(err)
print(" ВЫВОД ".center(80, '='))
print(out)
```

В результате получим что-то вроде этого:

```
==================================== ОШИБКИ ====================================

==================================== ВЫВОД =====================================

Обмен пакетами с google.com [74.125.205.102] с 32 байтами данных:
Ответ от 74.125.205.102: число байт=32 время=33мс TTL=108
Ответ от 74.125.205.102: число байт=32 время=35мс TTL=108
Ответ от 74.125.205.102: число байт=32 время=34мс TTL=108
Ответ от 74.125.205.102: число байт=32 время=33мс TTL=108

Статистика Ping для 74.125.205.102:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 4, потеряно = 0
    (0% потерь)
Приблизительное время приема-передачи в мс:
    Минимальное = 33мсек, Максимальное = 35 мсек, Среднее = 33 мсек
```